# How to set nonblocking configuration (for increasing concurrency) in Dropwizard 1.3.4?

Tags: concurrency, dropwizard, nonblocking

I was earlier using Dropwizard 0.6.3 for a service. It had a parameter connectorType where one could specify value 'nonblocking' and it would handle very high concurrency with 1024 max threads.

But after moving to Dropwizard 1.3.4 I can't achieve similar concurrency with 1024 max threads. I have to increase maxThreads in proportion to the concurrency I want to achieve.

I looked around a bit but couldn't find a way to set connector type to nonblocking. It is not a server config in Dropwizard 1.3.4 .

Is there no support for non blocking in higher dropwizard versions? If not then how should I go about achieving high concurrency?